# Return https.get() response body to client with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to develop a google cloud function that will make an external https GET request and return the response body to the client.

**Flow:**

1. client makes request to mockServer function
2. function makes GET request to example.com
3. function returns "results" from response body from example.com to client

```js
exports.mockServer = (req, res) => {
    'use strict';
    var https = require('https');
    
    var options = {
        host: 'example.com',
      path: '/path',
      headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'X-API-Key': 'XXXX'
      }
    };

if (req.method == 'GET'){
https.get(options, function (res) {
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function () {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                  var res_body = JSON.parse(data);
                  var results = JSON.stringify(res_body.result)
                    console.log("results:"+results);
            } else {
                console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            }
        });
    }).on('error', function (err) {
          console.log('Error:', err);
    });

} else {
  console.log("Wrong Method");
}   
  res.end()
};
```

I am able to successfully log the results with `console.log("results:"+results);` but I cannot figure out how to get it returned to the client. I am still new to this and am learning, so thank you so much in advance to any help!

Comment: First, there are much easier libraries you can use to make an API request.  Second, your `res` inside your https callback is masking the `res` from mockServer, which is what you need to use send a response to the client.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I’ll try renaming. Do you have any recommended libraries? I saw the request library was deprecated so wasn’t sure of the next best option

Comment: axios, ky, node-fetch, there're a lot

Comment: thank you both! I went with axios and it's working. I added the working code above.

Comment: Note: rather than update your question with the solution, consider answering your own question and accepting the answer to let others know that you've arrived at the solution. Although it may seem weird to answer your own question, it's 100% allowed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Posting @YouthDev's solution as an answer:

Thanks to @DougStevenson and @Deko in the comments, I switched to an `axios library` and it works like a charm. Thank you to both for pointing me in the correct direction. Below is the working axios code.

```
exports.mockServer = (req, res) => {
  const axios = require('axios').create({
    baseURL: 'https://example.com'
  });
  return axios.get('/path',{ headers: {'accept': 'application/json','X-API-Key': 'XXXXXX'} })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    return res.status(200).json({
      message: response.data
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    })
  })

};
```